# What is the "Templates" folder in the home directory for?

Tags: nautilus, xdg

For as long as I can remember, every time I install Ubuntu there is a folder in the home directory called "Templates." I've always just deleted it, but I'm curious: what's it supposed to be used for, and why is it in the default install?

Comment: Great question. I've always done the same thing, deleting the folder after installing. I think @fossfreedom just made our lives a little bit easier.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

If you drop any files in this folder, for example

[image]

then when you right-click and create a new document, you can select any of these files as a basis for the new file - i.e. a template.

[image]

For as long as I remember, this has always been a standard feature on many desktops such as Gnome.

---

If you have deleted the folder and need to restore this functionality:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Check that there is a line containing the following - if not, add this line.

```
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
```

Comment: You just answered hours of questions.

Comment: So does this play well with OpenDocument templates, eg .ott files and the like?

Comment: Does freedesktop specify the list of "well known" directories and what they should do somewhere, or is the `xdg-user-dir` implementation all we get? https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/

Comment: Thanks, This works great on `ext4` mounts but on filesystem types `fuse` or `cifs` mounts *(i.e. network drives and local ntfs drives)* the **executable flag** gets set automatically upon creation of the file. How can I inhibit this?

Comment: @Mark, your link doesn't work. I point here to your other answer https://askubuntu.com/a/652664/15943

Comment: @jdpipe, probably it doens't play well with ott template files. It will create another template rather than a real document.

Comment: If you want to be able to create "folder templates" (in addition to single-file templates), take a look at the Nautilus extension available at https://gitlab.com/edgimar/nautilus-new-folder-from-template

Comment: Note that this Templates folder isn't recognised by KDE; on Kubuntu, add a .desktop file in /usr/share/templates/ with the corresponding example file in /usr/share/templates/.source/ (guide here: https://dev.to/ksckaan1/creating-a-template-on-kde-plasma-3a9o )