# Templates in lubuntu not working

Tags: lubuntu, templates

I can't seem to create templates in Lubuntu. I have a folder in `~` called Templates, which I directly copied from my previous home folder when I installed Lubuntu 12.10, but when I right click in the file manager, in the create new menu, none of my templates are there!

Lubuntu doesn't use nautilus but PCMan File Manager. According to [this](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/05/29/pcman-lightweight-alternative-file-manager/) website, PCManFM has template functionality. I'm using version 1.0.1.

I've looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for) FAQ, and checked my `user-dirs.dirs` file and it indeed contains this line: `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"`

Comment: Could it be that LibreOffice is not installed (it's not in default Lubuntu) and your templates are LibreOffice templates?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not have LibreOffice installed, and some of my templates are .odt format, however I also have templates for latex and python, and they also do not show up in the menu!

Comment: I can confirm that templates dont work. I have tried in Lubuntu 13.04 on a Dell Latitude e4300 laptop and Lubuntu 12.04 on a home made PC. If i right-click on the desktop, there is not even an option to create a file from template, not even under the "Create New" header.