# How can I restore template functionality after having deleted the Templates folder in 12.10?

Tags: unity, nautilus, directory, templates

As many I deleted the *Templates* on a fresh install. I followed the instructions in the accepted answer of [What is the templates folder in the home dir for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for) I am running 12.10 and the proposed solution to restore the templates functionality does not work.

I did reboot. I tried a .Templates folder and a Templates folder and I played with XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates". I added empty libreoffice files etc. All without success.

How can I restore template functionality in 12.10?

Comment: btw, I think the Templates dir should contain a README placeholder on a fresh install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Ubuntu Tweak](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak) , It comes with some pre-installed template that you can add to your shortcuts in tweak section.

[image: Ubuntu Tweak Admins Page]

[image: Template Section Of Ubuntu Tweak]

[image: Adding Templates To Your Template Folder]

[image: View Of Your Template Folder After Adding Templates]

Comment: If you have deleted the templates folder, however, you first have to add in Ubuntu Tweak/Admin/User Folder.

Comment: To clarify, just in case, in Ubuntu Tweak, select Admins, select User Folder, and then select the Templates line.  Click Restore.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the system where your template directory is first:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Then edit: `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"`

Now, just drop any blank document from LibreOffice, a text editor or other into `~/Templates`.

When you right click in a Nautilus directory it will offer to open a new document with all the properties of the one you planted in Templates. Damn useful!

Comment: It appears the OP tried that and found it to not work, hence the need for this question. It didn't work for me either, even after a reboot.