# add LibreOffice to Nautilus right click `create new document` menu

Tags: nautilus, libreoffice

How do I add `LibreOffice` word processing to the options on the `Nautilus` right click `create new document` menu?

I'm on 12.04.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "Create new document" dialog sources its entries from `~/Templates`. Simply put an empty Libreoffice document in that folder or create a subfolder with multiple documents and you will be able to create LO documents from the context menu in Nautilus.

The same method applies to any other type of file, of course.

Comment: There is no ~/Templates folder.  I created it.  It now contains "Untitled 1.odt" which is an empty LibreOffice word processing document.  The right-click menu still does not offer LibreOffice.

Comment: @broiyan That's strange, especially if you're on 12.04. Templates work fine here. You might have to adapt the folder name to your locale. Are your other standard home folders in English or another language? (e.g. Pictures, Music, Video). Make sure to put the folder under your own username (e.g. /home/broiyan/Templates). Please see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/208291/how-to-create-a-new-blank-file-in-nautilus-3-6) for more information.

Comment: @broiyan One user there reports a similar issue, where the Templates folder is not recognized. [He found a solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/208291/how-to-create-a-new-blank-file-in-nautilus-3-6#comment298944_209669), which might work for you.

Comment: [The solution is also outlined in this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/a/94739/81372).

Comment: Thanks Glutanimate.  The problem is that `~/Templates` was deleted and to restore it you need to use `Ubuntu Tweak`.  Once restored, adding empty documents works as you have described. This link describes using `Ubuntu Tweak` to restore the folder.  [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233550/how-can-i-restore-template-functionality-after-having-deleted-the-templates-fold)

Comment: A large pack of templates can be downloaded from here http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=129681

Comment: And whatever you name the file will be the name that shows up in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Nautilus Actions.

> Nautilus-action allows you to define custom actions or commands for
>   certain file types or files with names matching your description.
>   There are plenty of things that you can do with nautilus-action.

To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

When its done, search for nautilus in Dash, and click on it.

[image]

Once it opens, you well see the program, and then you can create a new context menu.

[image]

Comment: Is a new menu really necessary when the existing menu already allows the creation of new documents, unfortunately, only a text file. In any event, this did not work for me.  Are these instructions complete?  What will go into this menu? Does this menu invoke LibreOffice and if so, then how?

Comment: If you want the open with Libreoffice, then you need to add that menu. To add it just follow the screens in Nautilus Actions.  The instructions are complete, you just have to actually create the menu.  Look at this [example](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/368016:nautilus-actions-extend-the-functionality-and-flexibility-of-the-file-manager), it will help.

Comment: This [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus) will help you as well.