# Create full folder structure from "New document" (Templates) menu

Tags: nautilus, directory, templates

If I create a folder inside Templates, when I click "new Document" > "myfolder" it does nothing.  That is just a sub directory to organize the templates.

But maybe it would be useful to create that folder hierarchy. For instance:

I have all these files and folders:

- ~/template/tm1.txt
- ~/template/tm2.txt
- ~/template/myfolder/
- ~/template/myfolder/subfolder/
- ~/template/myfolder/subfolder/hello1.html
- ~/template/myfolder/subfolder/hello2.html
- ~/template/myfolder/subfolder/hello3.html
- ~/template/myfolder/index.html

So when I click "new Document" > "myfolder" I'd like to create "myfolder" with "subfolder" and index.html (etc....).

Is there any way to do this?

I know that "new Document" isn't the same as "new folder", but maybe this should be called "new template".

Comment: Not as elegant as other answers but simple. You can create a compressed file with directories inside and create a copy from the template and immediately uncompress it (with right click) (and delete the compressed file).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible via the Templates menu but you could create a Nautilus script to achieve the same. Something akin to the following should work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Create folder structure from template

TemplateDir="$HOME/Folder templates/dir1"
WorkingDir="$PWD"

cp -r "$TemplateDir" "$WorkingDir/"
```

Place your folder with subfolders and files in `~/Folder templates` and modify the `TemplateDir` line accordingly. Then follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-can-i-install-a-nautilus-script) to install the script.

When you're done, right click on an empty area in your Nautilus window and select *Scripts* → *your script name*. This should create a copy of your template directory in the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Nautilus extension that hopefully does what you're looking for.  See the following website:

[nautilus-new-folder-from-template](https://gitlab.com/edgimar/nautilus-new-folder-from-template)

This extension allows you to create directory-templates, and choose from among them using the right-click context menu.

Comment: Doesn't work. It looks like it would without  `nautilus-new-folder-from-template`: http://i.imgur.com/xHTx7tU.png (Yes, I restarted Nautilus.)

Comment: hi @Mark, this repository is no longer (publicly) available. Has it been moved somewhere else?

Comment: @dukwon - the URL (and code) is now updated and should be working correctly with Ubuntu 20.04.  To UTF-8: the image you show indicates that the (old version of the) extension failed to load.