# Templates directory in Ubuntu: can I use this feature with gedit in bash shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, gedit, templates

Saw this question:
[What is the "Templates" folder in the home directory for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for)
But I wanted to know whether I can use this feature with gedit in bash shell?
If yes How?
If no is there any other way to create templates for gedit?

Comment: Thanks Zaka. I used ur idea to create a bash function to automatically create a file with the template. gtp () { if [ $1==*.py ]; then cat ~/Templates/exn.py > $1; gedit $1; fi }

Answer (score 0):

No, bacause that behaviour is associated to the desktop.

However you can do this:

```
cp $HOME/Templates/example\ gedit.txt myNewFile.txt
gedit myNewFile.txt
```