# Are there special functionalities to Ubuntu default directories in home?

Tags: 16.04, home-directory

A fresh Ubuntu (16.04.3) installation comes with a home directory ~/ that is filled with the following default folders:

- Music
- Videos
- Pictures
- Documents
- Templates
- ...

From [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for), I know that the `~/Templates` folder has a special functionality (adding template documents to it will allow you to use these templates when doing `right-click, new document` anywhere).

The furthermore present `~/Desktop`, `~/Public` and `~/Downloads` directory functionalities are more obvious.

However, about the other directories (`~/Documents`, `~/Music`, `~/Videos`, `~/Pictures`), I was wondering whether any of those also has a special functionality - or whether it is fine/sensible to just delete them?

Comment: An example would be what file or folder exactly

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, I clarified the question with an edit.

Comment: One special functionality is that the names of these directories can be translated [automatically] to another language, if you install another language and set your system to use it. Some application programs use these programs as targets (for example for created or downloaded files).

Comment: There are two additional folders with special meaning: If there is a `./bin` folder, it is added to the PATH variable, so you can call scripts/programs in there without specifying a path. And `./public_html` is by default used by apache (maybe other webservers as well), if users are allowed to publish their own content.