# How to add a new file in any directory by right-click add a new ...file (text, doc etc.) easily?

Tags: 18.04, files, text, doc

I want to add a new file to any directory by just one or two clicks. There is a way like using the terminal and touch command, but I want it to be easier so that it can be done by anybody. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

To create 'new document' option in right click menu, do the following:
Check if Templates directory exists:

> ls ~/Templates

If it doesn't exist, create the directory:

> mkdir ~/Templates

Now, to create templates of the desired new documents, it is sufficient to create them with the appropriate names in **Templates** directory. For instance, to create a template of empty document:

> touch ~/Templates/'Empty Document'

Then you will find the option **New Document/Empty Document** in the right click menu in your file manager.

To create other document templates:

> touch ~/Templates/'New Text Document.txt'

or

> touch ~/Templates/New\ PNG\ Image.png

and so on...

Reference: https://ostechnix.com/how-to-add-new-document-option-in-right-click-context-menu-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 2):

After looking for this I managed to do it by adding template files to Home/Templates directory.
Firstly open an app, like text editor. (You can tap on start button and type text editor, it will pop up)
Then click on save the file. (Ctrl+S or click on save)
On the opening window, choose Templates directory and give the file a good name like "txt file".
Click on save.
You will see a button on right click on a folder named New Document. When you come on this New Document option, you will see the "txt file".

[Adding file to the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpKXO.png)

Also: [What is the "Templates" folder in the home directory for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for)