# How can I add create documents in ubuntu desktop

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

So I Know that desktop feature was removed from gnome for some reason but I don't get it how Zorin OS team were able to recreate the "create document" feature in desktop. If there is an option please tell me.

Comment: Please describe more precisely the function you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a new file in any directory by right click add a new ...file (text, doc etc.) easily?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294225/how-to-add-a-new-file-in-any-directory-by-right-click-add-a-new-file-text-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Gnome extension that allows this, go to  https://extensions.gnome.org and install Desktop Icons: Neo by mawi

Comment: Please check your link.

Comment: That link works for me but try missing off the "local", that is https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: It also works for me, but it is not a correct link. Please correct.

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean. If I have done something wrong I will happily correct it, but you will first have to be clear about with what you consider to be "incorrect" about the working links.

Comment: Your link points to the Gnome Shell page showing locally installed extensions. So it it not there you install the new extension. At the very minimum, refer to https://extensions.gnome.org/ if you do not care directly linking to the extensions home page.

Comment: @vanadium
 I did refer to https://extensions.gnome.org/ in my reply to your comment above but you still claimed the link was not correct.

Comment: Strangem I still see https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ typed out in your message, and a link https://extensions.gnome.org/local/